# Generate multiple symbolic links while maintaining directory structure

Tags: shell-script, find, symlink

I want to generate symbolic links from multiple folders while maintaining the directory structure. I read a few answers and the best thing I can come up with now is:

```
find /data/DIV5/SASC/e042_ctcl/input/*/Clean_data/*/*/*.fq.gz -type f -exec ln -sf \{\} . \;
```

This generates symlinks all in the same directory. But what I want is to have the same directory structure as in the `find` command and if possible using the same structure as the input. For example: `input/*/Clean_data/*/*/*.fq.gz`

When files and directories are matched the symlink should follow the same structure as the absolute link found with the `find` command.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: As a side note, `cp -rs` could have been used if you had to link all the files, not just a couple of them (`*.fq.gz`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I whould generate the commands with `awk` and then pipe them into `bash`:

```
find /data/DIV5/SASC/e042_ctcl/input/*/Clean_data/*/*/*.fq.gz -type f | \
awk '{printf "mkdir -p `dirname %s`\nln -s %s ./%s \n", substr($0, 27), $0, substr($0, 27)}'
```

This generates a list of the commands, I would first control them and then finally pipe it to `bash`. The complete command would be:

```
find /data/DIV5/SASC/e042_ctcl/input/*/Clean_data/*/*/*.fq.gz -type f | \
awk '{printf "mkdir -p `dirname %s`\nln -s %s ./%s \n", substr($0, 27), $0, substr($0, 27)}' | bash
```

Comment: I think there's a tiny bug. I did a test and 'm getting `mkdir -p \`dirname /usr/share/doc/xml-commons-apis/LICENSE.sac.html\`` and `ln -s /usr/share/doc/xml-commons-apis/LICENSE.sac.html ./-apis/LICENSE.sac.html`.

Comment: When you use the command as above? You have search results in `/usr/share/doc/` that cannot be when searching in `/data/DIV5/SASC/.../.../`. Please post the output of `find /data/DIV5/SASC/e042_ctcl/input/*/Clean_data/*/*/*.fq.gz -type f`

Comment: So that `27` is a hard-coded value for the particular directory mentioned in the question?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu yes, because he wanted the directory structure from input on, that's the 26th character

Comment: Then a +1 from me.

Comment: Actually it still fails because the commands that bash tries to execute are `mkdir -p /data/DIV5/SASC/e042_ctcl/input/y/Clean_data/3/c` and `ln -s /data/DIV5/SASC/e042_ctcl/input/y/Clean_data/3/c/foobar.fq.gz ./input/y/Clean_data/3/c/foobar.fq.gz`. You need to trim the output of `dirname` too.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu that's true thanks, i edited my post^^

Comment: Thanks for the answer will see what works best for me and than accept one of 2 answers as final!

Comment: Note that this assumes that there are no special characters in file names.

Answer (score 4):

Ugly and fragile, but it should get the job done:

```
find /data/DIV5/SASC/e042_ctcl/input/*/Clean_data/*/*/*.fq.gz -type f -print0 | \
  xargs -0 -n 1 \
    sh -c 'mkdir -p "$PWD/`dirname $0`"; ln -s "$0" "$PWD/`dirname $0`"'
```

Inspired by [chaos' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136375/1174), I came up with this alternative which also *trims unneeded directories*:

```
find /data/DIV5/SASC/e042_ctcl/input/*/Clean_data/*/*/*.fq.gz -type f   \
     -printf 'mkdir -p "${PWD}/%h"; ln -s "%p" \\\n\t"${PWD}/%h"\n'   | \
sed 's#/data/DIV5/SASC/e042_ctcl##'                                   | \
sh -
```

It generates the required **mkdir** and **ln** commands:

```
mkdir -p "${PWD}//data/DIV5/SASC/e042_ctcl/input/x/Clean_data/0/a"; ln -s "/data/DIV5/SASC/e042_ctcl/input/x/Clean_data/0/a/foobar.fq.gz" \
    "${PWD}//data/DIV5/SASC/e042_ctcl/input/x/Clean_data/0/a"
```

Then it removes the unneed directories from them with **sed**, resulting in:

```
mkdir -p "${PWD}//input/x/Clean_data/0/a"; ln -s "/data/DIV5/SASC/e042_ctcl/input/x/Clean_data/0/a/foobar.fq.gz" \
    "${PWD}//input/x/Clean_data/0/a"
```

The **ln** command starts on the same line as **mkdir** and continues on the next line in order to keep the source intact while trimming the destination. Printing them on the same line or each on its own distinct line would have required a more complicated **sed** script.

Explaination from the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Name-Directives.html) for **find**, of the `-printf` parameters:

> `%p`
>      File's name (not the absolute path name, but the name of the file as it was encountered by find - that is, as a relative path from one of the starting points).
>
> `%h`
>      Leading directories of file's name (all but the last element and the slash before it). If the file's name contains no slashes (for example because it was named on the command line and is in the current working directory), then “%h” expands to “.”. This prevents “%h/%f” expanding to “/foo”, which would be surprising and probably not desirable.

Comment: Woo thanks for the explanation will dive into it! was busy doing some other work till now, so sorry for late reply

Comment: Note that the commands based on `… | sh` break if files contain some special characters.

Comment: It would certainly fail for double quotes (`"`) because I used them for quoting, but it should work with multiple spaces or glob characters like `?` or `*`.

Answer (score 2):

I am with the impression that you are looking for a tool like [**GNU Stow**](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/).

> GNU Stow is a symlink farm manager which takes distinct packages of software and/or data located in separate directories on the filesystem, and makes them appear to be installed in the same place. For example, `/usr/local/bin` could contain symlinks to files within `/usr/local/stow/emacs/bin`, `/usr/local/stow/perl/bin` etc., and likewise recursively for any other subdirectories such as `.../share`, `.../man`, and so on.

Check it out, if it matches the use-case.

Answer (score 2):

Zsh has a convenient function [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv). First, load it (you can do this from your `.zshrc`, or on the command line for a one-session use):

```
autoload -U zmv
alias zcp='zmv -C'
alias zln='zmv -L'
```

To recreate a forest of symbolic links is as easy as this:

```
 zln -s '/data/DIV5/SASC/e042_ctcl/(input/*/Clean_data/*/*/*.fq.gz)' '$1'
```

If you want to traverse `Clean_data` directories recursively instead of going only exactly two levels deep:

```
 zln -s '/data/DIV5/SASC/e042_ctcl/(input/*/Clean_data/**/*.fq.gz)' '$1'
```

There is a big limitation: this won't create the necessary subdirectories. You can do that by defining and using a wrapper function for `ln` that creates directories as needed.

```
ln_s_mkdir () {
  mkdir -p -- ${(P)#}
  ln -s "$@"
}
 zmv -p ln_s_mkdir '/data/DIV5/SASC/e042_ctcl/(input/*/Clean_data/**/*.fq.gz)' '$1'
```

You can make the command run a bit faster by using zsh's [internal `mkdir` and `ln` commands](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002ffiles-Module) (which are not loaded by default because they have fewer options that the GNU utilities found on most systems).

```
zmodload -F zsh/files b:zf_ln b:zf_mkdir
ln_s_mkdir () {
  zf_mkdir -p -- ${(P)#}
  zf_ln -s "$@"
}
 zmv -p ln_s_mkdir '/data/DIV5/SASC/e042_ctcl/(input/*/Clean_data/**/*.fq.gz)' '$1'
```